# Function Call ordering in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using java-query to generate a chess board on page load:

Basically I have an empty body:

```
<body>
</body>
```

I then have the following javascript linked:

```
var addsquareblack=function(i,row){$(document).ready(function(){

    var square=$('<div class="square"></div>');
    if ((i%2)===0)
        {square.css('background-color','brown');}
    $('.row').last().append(square);
});};

var addsquarewhite=function(i,row){$(document).ready(function(){

    var square=$('<div class="square"></div>');
    if ((i%2)===0)
        {square.css('background-color','white');}
        else
        {square.css('background-color','brown');}
    $('.row').last().append(square);
});};

var create=function(a){$(document).ready(function(){
    var row=$('<div class="row"></div>');
    $('body').append(row);
    if ((a%2)===0)
    {for(var i=1;i<9;i++){addsquareblack(i,row);}}
    else
    {for(var i=1;i<9;i++){addsquarewhite(i,row);}}
});};

var addrows=function(){
    for(var i=1;i<9;i++){create(i);}
    };
```

I then call in a script in head:

```
<script> addrows() </script>
```

However, the `addsquarewhite` and `addsquare` black are not functioning properly:  My `div`s with class `row` are being added to `body` correctly, but then all of the squares that I am adding are getting bunched into the very last `div`.  I thought that they would get added only to the last `div` available at the time of the method call.  Clearly I don't understand something about scope/flow in javascript.  Please enlighten.
Thanks!

Comment: At first look, how you are using document.ready is wrong, it should be something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axsvL/1/

Comment: I strongly suggest to you to use `:odd` and `:even` pseudoclasses in css (or with sizzle), append 64 divs and use style to have a new row every `-nth(8n)` elements

Comment: Arun:  Yes that fixed it.  Using document.ready within each separate function was creating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also your usage on `ready` handler is wrong

It is because you are adding the `square` elements to the last row instead of the row.

```
$('.row').last().append(square)
```

instead

```
var addsquareblack=function(i,row){
    var square=$('<div class="square">1</div>');
    if ((i%2)===0) {
        square.css('background-color','brown');
    }
    row.append(square);
};

var addsquarewhite=function(i,row){
    var square=$('<div class="square">2</div>');
    if ((i%2)===0) {
        square.css('background-color','white');
    } else {
        square.css('background-color','brown');
    }
    row.append(square);
};

var create=function(a){

    var row=$('<div class="row"></div>');
    $('body').append(row);
    if ((a%2)===0) {
        for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
            addsquareblack(i,row);
        }
    } else {
        for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
            addsquarewhite(i,row);
        }
    }

};

var addrows=function(){
    for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
        create(i);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    addrows();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axsvL/)

Comment: This also works;  I should have deleted the second parameter on my function because I had already gotten it to work by simply passing in the variable row to the add... function.  I was looking for a way to get it to work without having to pass that variable.  But fixing my use of document.ready accomplished that! Thanks